# Best way to get Child Elements in Expandable Listview in android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I just gone through some of the examples about creating Expandable Listview in Android. But different sites are following different procedures.
Can u please suggest me What is the best practice for creating Expandable listview in android?
Thanks in advance